# this reference in a jQuery UI Custom widget

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have built a custom widget that contains lots of other widgets.

The problem I am getting is the **this.** reference when a widget inside my custom widget calls a function in my custom widget. For example:

```
$(function() {
    $.widget("custom.my_widget",
    {
        _create: function() {
            this.variable = "HI";
            var that=this;
            // A Custom widget
            this.button = $("<button>", {html:"PRESS"})
            .button()
            .click(this.do_it) // I know I can do a function(){ that.do_it() }) but that is not the point
            .appendTo(this.element);
        },

        do_it: function() {
            // With the setup like this, how do I get the correct this. reference 
            // As it stands, this = the button object
            alert("TEST: "+ this.variable);
        }
   })
});
```

The problem is that the **this** in the do_it function does not point to my_custom widget, instead it points to the button widget.

Above is symbolic, please don't point out a bug as my actual widget is over 3000 lines of code and has many references like this.  I need to get the my_widget instance inside functions like this when other widgets call my widget's functions.

I have tried putting in another parameter, but with some callbacks in some third party widgets this is not possible.

There must be an easy way to get the correct base **this** value for my_widget.

jsFiddle for reference : http://jsfiddle.net/jplevene/6e7m2q6h/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `bind()`, instead of `click()`, specifying the "context", or just reference a local variable and call the function (e.g. `self` below):

```
$.widget("custom.my_widget",
{
    // the constructor
    _create: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.variable = "HI";

        // A Custom widget
        this.button = $("<button>").button().click(function(){
            self.do_it();
        });
    },

    do_it: function(e) {
        alert(this.variable);
    }
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewpgv3mt/1/

Comment: This does not help, I said that it was symbolic.  Yours still returns this.variable as undefined.

Comment: @Justin Levene: Have mocked up a JSFiddle showing this code does alert "HI" as expected.

Comment: @Justin Levene: Thanks. The comment in your JSFiddle implies you do not want to use the *normal way* of solving this common Javascript problem. Not sure why you think there is a magic plugin solution instead, as this is just a basic Javascript *function/context scoping* issue. Please clarify why the normal solution to this problem is insufficient?

Comment: The normal solution is no good as third party widgets (not shown in the fiddle) like jqGrid when setting "formatter" use the method shown in the fiddle.

Comment: Best show a specific formatter code example, including a third party widget, as I use third-party widgets from within my own plugins all the time and not had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to do it is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $.widget("custom.my_widget",
    {
        _create: function() {
            this.variable = "HI";
            // A Custom widget
            this.button = $("<button>", {html:"PRESS"})
            .button()
            .click(this.do_it) // I know I can do a function(){ that.do_it() }) but that is not the point
            .data("widget", this)  // <---- New line here
            .appendTo(this.element);
        },

        do_it: function() {
            // Get the parent widget
            var that = $(this).data("widget");
            alert("TEST: "+ that.variable);
        }
   })
});
```

What I did was pass the "this" value to a data value of the object.  There must be a better way than this.

I have tried $(this).closest(".my_widget_class"), but I then need the widget from the object

Comment: That is similar to what most plugins do behind the scenes (on the primary element only) but you still do not explain your comment in the code: *Why* don't you want to use anonymous function (e.g. `function(){ that.do_it() })`). *Why* is that "not the point"? :)